# How can I read a property-name of an object with blanks

Tags: javascript

```
const scraper = require("table-scraper"); //scrape a html table
scraper
   .get("https://www.gkd.bayern.de/de/meteo/wind/isar/ammerseeboje-16601050/messwerte/tabelle") 
      //that is the list of wind values for each hour
   .then(function (tableData) {
      console.log(tableData[1]); //that is the table as an object
  })
```

console returns :

```
 [
    { Datum: '05.06.2021 21:00', 'Wind [m/s]': '5,7' },
    { Datum: '05.06.2021 20:00', 'Wind [m/s]': '5,4' },
....
]
```

tableData[1][0].Datum - ok defines the datum

but

tableData[1][0].'Wind [m/s]' - will return undefined...

How can I get the value of eg. 5,7?

Thanks

Comment: Try: `tableData[1][0]['Wind [m/s]']`

Comment: _“will return undefined”_ — No, it’ll throw a syntax error.

Comment: [Duplicate](//google.com/search?q=site%3Astackoverflow.com+js+access+property+with+spaces) of [How can I access a JavaScript object which has spaces in the object's key?](/q/8317982/4642212).

Answer (score 1):

```js
const tableData = [{
    Datum: '05.06.2021 21:00',
    'Wind [m/s]': '5,7'
  },
  {
    Datum: '05.06.2021 20:00',
    'Wind [m/s]': '5,4'
  }
]


console.log(tableData[0]['Wind [m/s]'])
```

Answer (score -1):

I'm not completely sure I understand the questions but if you're trying to return the value `5,7` I'm thinking you might need something like this:

```js
const data = [{
    Datum: '05.06.2021 21:00',
    'Wind [m/s]': '5,7'
  },
  {
    Datum: '05.06.2021 20:00',
    'Wind [m/s]': '5,4'
  }
]

console.log(data[0][`Wind [m/s]`])
```

Answer (score -2):

```js
const obj =  [
    { Datum: '05.06.2021 21:00', 'Wind [m/s]': '5,7' },
    { Datum: '05.06.2021 20:00', 'Wind [m/s]': '5,4' }]
    
console.log(obj[0]['Wind [m/s]'])

console.log(Object.values(obj[0])[1]);
```